# How to bin age data into categories - issues with setting highs and lows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I need to put 'F1: AGE' into categorical bins: (unknown, 17 and under, 18-25, 26-35, 36-45, 46-55, 56+)

I have replaced all non-numeric values with a missing values. So far my code is:

```
age_index = df['F1: AGE'].str.isnumeric()
age_index = age_index.fillna(False)
dfy.loc[~age_index, 'F1: AGE'] = np.nan
```

From here, I am not sure where to go. I am wanting to use pd.cut() but what I have tried has given me:

```
Error: Bin edges must be unique
```

Along with about a dozen other errors from overthinking, I am completely stuck. Any help on how to create these bins and labels and have them properly work would be great.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! when asking about errors, it's really hard for us to debug statements like "I tried ... a dozen other things". instead, it's really helpful if you can pick one, give us the exact code that you tried, and include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback). Feel free to describe what else you tried, but we need a concrete example of how you're trying to tackle this so we can spot what's going wrong. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) you do need to provide uniqe bin edges - usually this would be something like this:

```py
binned = pd.cut(my_data, bins=[-np.inf, 17, 25, 35, 45, 55, np.inf])
```

optionally you can use `labels` to name your bins however you'd like:

```py
binned = pd.cut(
    my_data,
    bins=[-np.inf, 17, 25, 35, 45, 55, np.inf],
    labels=["17 and under", "18-25", "26-35", "36-45", "46-55", "56+"],
)
```